# Autorotation is not happening properly

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am working the Autorotation for iPad, but i am facing a weird problem.

the problem is if i start using the ipad as portrait view and rotate the ipad in to landscape. it is showing the sizing of portait but not landscape. in the same way if i start using the ipad as Landscape view and rotate the ipad in to portrait view. it is showing the sizing of Landscape but not Portrait. i am using the below code to change the sizing of objects

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

 UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
        || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        table.frame = CGRectMake(83, 600, 550, 275);
           im.frame = CGRectMake(0, 62, 775, 70);
          im1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 135, 775, 40);
        im2.frame = CGRectMake(60, 325, 650, 550);
         l17.frame = CGRectMake(0, 62, 775, 70);
        l16.frame = CGRectMake(85, 145, 780, 40);
           l15.frame = CGRectMake(83, 200, 600, 40);
        img.frame = CGRectMake(550, 300, 150, 110);
        l18.frame = CGRectMake(28, 550, 650, 40);
           b7.frame = CGRectMake(83, 880, 600, 40);
        //[self.view addSubview:table];

    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Kindly suggest me whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
        table.frame = CGRectMake(83, 600, 550, 275);
        im.frame = CGRectMake(0, 62, 775, 70);
        im1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 135, 775, 40);
        im2.frame = CGRectMake(60, 325, 650, 550);
        l17.frame = CGRectMake(0, 62, 775, 70);
        l16.frame = CGRectMake(85, 145, 780, 40);
        l15.frame = CGRectMake(83, 200, 600, 40);
        img.frame = CGRectMake(550, 300, 150, 110);
        l18.frame = CGRectMake(28, 550, 650, 40);
        b7.frame = CGRectMake(83, 880, 600, 40);
    else
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,73,320,390);
        --
        --

}
```

Have you tried like this?

Comment: it is not passing through this method

Answer (score 0):

**Code for Checking Orientation Working or Not ?**

Code ::

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
    ......
}
```

Check Method ::

```
-(void)orientationChanged {

   NSLog(@"Orientation Changed..!!");

   UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;

   //Lanscape View
   if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
    || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
   {
       table.frame = CGRectMake(83, 600, 550, 275);
       .....
   }

   //Portrait View
   else
   {
       table.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
       .....
   }
}
```

**Code for Orientation Changed Methods**

In PCH File,

```
#define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6        ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] < 6.0 )
#define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] >= 6.0 )
```

In .m file,

```
//For Less than IOS 6

#ifdef IOS_OLDER_THAN_6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
   return toInterfaceOrientation;
}
#endif

// For Newer than IOS 6.
#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
#endif
```

Hopefully, it'll be help to you.

Thanks.